# Multi-Criteria Index Match Array with Start/End Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a multi-criteria index match array that returns a target value if the range value falls between, or is equal to the range in two other columns.

Dataset I need to index match and have found values populated: in `Sheet1`. The formula will be written in `Sheet1:D2` and `Sheet2:E2`.

```
#  Col. A       Col. B              Col. C           Col. D     Col. E
1   Line        Beginning Marker    Ending Marker    Volume     %Volume
2   021F        32983               45938
3   050A        8583                17839
4   300B        28849               893980
5   0405-01     583                 17849
6   101         21903               87489
```

Storage dataset in `Sheet2` that holds values I want matched in `Sheet1`

```
#   Col. A     Col. B             Col. C            Col. D     Col. E
1   Line       Beginning Marker   Ending Marker     Volume     % Volume
2   021F       0                  57876             880        0.2
3   050A       0                  21453             388        0.4
4   300A       0                  1124640           1120       0.3
5   0617-06    0                  21890             895        0.1
6   300B       0                  1308830           456        0.4
7   196A2-01   0                  1892              880        0.5
8   0405-01    0                  21382             750        0.4
9   101        0                  109488            800        0.3
```

What the end result should look like:

```
#   Col. A      Col. B              Col. C          Col. D    Col. E
1   Line        Beginning Marker    Ending Marker   Volume    % Volume
2   021F        32983               45938           880       0.2
3   050A        8583                17839           388       0.4
4   300B        28849               893980          456       0.4
5   0405-01     583                 17849           750       0.4
6   101         21903               87489           800       0.3
```

This is the formula I've been working with trying to get the right result, but I fear it will only work if there was 1 number that was to be searched to see if it fell between a range of values, not search a range within a range.

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A:A)*(Sheet1!B2>=Sheet2!B:B)*Sheet1!C2<=Sheet2!C:C),0))}
```

An example workbook [with no macros] can be found [HERE](https://ufile.io/d0v9o)

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Each Line in Sheet1 only occurs only once within Sheet2.

Comment: Sheet2 is a hypothetical. I should have specified there will be duplicates on occasion, or some with slight variances in Sheet1.

Comment: Perhaps update your example workbook such that it reflects more closely the reality.